# iPhone images portrait and landscape modes HTML5

Tags: iphone, html, image, retina

Hi there ive been searching the web but cant really find a definitive answer.

I am currently converting an html5 website to be used on an iphone.

My query is about images, the portrait mode is 320x960 px and landscape is 960x320px

for the retina display rather than set my images to be 320x * (height is proportional) i hvae set them to be png's at 640 x *

i am setting the image width too 100% and the viewport size to 320px

Is this correct for the retina display?

When the device orientation is changes am i going to lose quality when those existing images are are 100% in landscape mode, my client wants to be able to use pinch zoom to zoom in.

SO do i need to have 1 image for portrait mode, i image for landscape mode, and then swap the source url with jquery?

All the images are stored in a database but i can manipulate which folder they come from where i have so one set of images will be in a landscape folder, and another set in a portrait folder.

I hopr this makes sense and someone can put me right on image resoloutions
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes a retina display uses the same dimensional pixel based layout as a standard webpage / or native app build for that matter.  The part that trips people up is the source files need to be double the size of the size of the object in your page.

For example here's an image tag with a source file of 40px X 40px.

```
<img src="retina-images/my-button-40x40.png" width="20" height="20">
```